# CSS does not work when I return to same page in JSF

Tags: css, jsf, netbeans, xhtml, netbeans-8

I'm working in my final university project of this year using JSF and NetBeans 8.2. But I have a problem with css. When I login I save the category using this line:

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("categoria", cat);
```

That's work fine, I debug it.
It's redirects me, to main page, for my category, in this case:
[image of page with css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4tBM.png)
Then I press **Main Menu button** and It's redirects me to main page of my category [Main menu botton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvXh4.png) and that's the error, the same page of first picture without css [same page of picture one, without css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Abk.png). The links works fine, and the page have css, but the css does not working when I go back. 
Head of this main page:

```
  <h:head>
    <link href="../resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../resources/css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Gestionar Plan Anual Departamento</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
</h:head>
```

Sorry my English, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the tag: `<link/>`. This is not the correct tag for work with *.xhtml, the correct tag is: `<h:outputStylesheet/>`.
Finally, I remplace

```
<h:head>
<link href="../resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../resources/css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<title>Gestionar Plan Anual Departamento</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
```

By:

```
 <h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/principal.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <title>Gestionar Plan Anual Departamento</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> </meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
</h:head>
```